# Youtube Video Playing issue in Android - Code Attached

Tags: android, android-emulator, android-widget, youtube-api

This is a critical issue pertaining to an application we did. The code snippet attached here was working like a charm for the past several months. All of a sudden, it gives us the message in mediaplayer that video cannot be played.

Can anyone please suggest what need to be done, in order that this code will work for me by playing the video with no hassles.

Looking forward for your valuable comments, help and suggestions,

Please follow this link in order to view the code which was working perfectly -- http://pastebin.com/NVT8eBC0

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.media.MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.MediaController;
import android.widget.VideoView;

public class videoact extends Activity implements OnPreparedListener{
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        MediaController mc = new MediaController(this);
        VideoView vv = (VideoView)findViewById(R.id.VideoView01);
        try
        {
         Uri ur = Uri.parse("http://youtube.com/get_video?video_id=ZmX7zLCrcAI&t=vjVQa1PpcFPmrj_j5y370BhPYfq3qHoWsFICYcBqEl4%3D&asv=&fmt=18");
         vv.setVideoURI(ur);
         vv.setMediaController(mc);
         vv.requestFocus();
         vv.start();
         mc.show();
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
         System.out.print(e.getMessage() + "error");
        }

    }

public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {
// TODO Auto-generated method stub
mp.start();
}

}
```

Comment: Post the code here instead of pastebin. There is a code button to format the code properly.

Comment: Hi Michael, It was not aligning the code properly when I tried to do that.

Comment: Hello, anyone there who can say what the issue is?

Answer (score 0):

You can't play YouTube videos like that. Use the Android YouTube Player Api or the IFrame API in a WebView. 
Using the get_video endpoint is against youtube's terms of service. 
https://www.youtube.com/static?template=terms

> You agree not to access Content through any technology or means other than the video playback pages of the Service itself, the Embeddable Player, or other explicitly authorized means YouTube may designate.